# What is the name of the below method??

Tags: limits, terminology

what is the name of the rule that calculates limits such as
limit $\dfrac{x^6-64}{x^4-16}$ when $x$ tends to $2$
so the answer is $6/4$ times $2^{6-4}$
no L'Hopital's Rule
and the general formula of the law is
limit $\dfrac{x^a-c^a}{x^b-c^b}$ when $x$ tends to $c$ = $a/b$ * $c^{a-b}$
I just want to remember the name of the rule

Comment: "Factoring"? (to cancel a $x-2$ factor from numerator and denominator)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but suppose that x was raised to the power 100 or something in the numerator and denumerator u won't be able to use factoring,and I remember a rule that solves such limits besides L'Hopital's rule

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $x^6 - 64 = (x^2)^3 - 4^3 = (x^2-4)(...)$, and $x^4-16 = (x^2)^2-4^2=(x^2-4)(...)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply but suppose that x was raised to the power 100 or something in the numerator and denumerator u won't be able to use factoring,and I remember a rule that solves such limits besides L'Hopital's rule